# Use same domain for two websites, depending on customer IP

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, url-rewriting, masking

Here's the scenario I want to know if possible and how:

Scenario

- Domain (`www.foo.com`) at one hosting provider.
- Two websites, one at `www.bar.com` and another one at `www.biz.com`, each at a different hosting provider.

Actions

- When a user enters `www.foo.com`, depending on the IP location, it will
  load `www.bar.com` or `www.biz.com`. It is important that the user sees 
  `www.foo.com` (masking, not redirecting).
- So a user from UK would navigate `www.foo.com` website (which is really `www.bar.com`) and a user from France would navigate `www.foo.com`
  website (which is really `www.biz.com`).

So far I have managed to find a "fix" which would consist of loading a small website with an iframe at the `www.foo.com` hosting, and loading the corresponding website in it. I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution than this.

Comment: Google 'geolocation load balancing'. Will cost money though. Obviously if you could use two different domains (example.co.uk and example.fr) that would be much easier.

Comment: What you’re asking for is essentially a reverse proxy. Requests for foo.com go to a web server which makes a reverse proxy request to bar.com or biz.com depending on the geolocation of the visitor. That’s all configurable within a web server like Apache or nginx.

Comment: Something let me think that we have XYproblem (http://xyproblem.info/) here. If you describe the final result perhaps you'll have better solution.

Comment: Is SEO a concern? Should `bar.com` and `biz.com` be accessible directly?

Answer (score 1):

Iframe will not work because you want to keep links e.g. from bar.com to bar.com/contact look like to foo.com/contact.

So, as @deceze said, you need to set up reverse proxy but also you need to configure something which will make search and replace inside the servers response. Perhaps there are many such tools, but just to name one: `privoxy`.